# bind ALL forms at once to jQuery Form possible?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-forms-plugin

Via `ajaxCall` I dynamically created a list of users, each user in a seperated form, handling moderator actions. Like:

```
<form id="'.$aSpeler['playerID'].'">
  <select name="aktieopspeler">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Kies actie</option>
    <option value="vakantiemodusIN">Vakantiemodus IN</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

All my forms are handled by the jQuery Form plugin (malsup).
The only solution I can think of, is also creating bindings for each form, but is it possible to bind all forms at once?

Code I use for an existing form:

```
var options = { 
    target:'#maincontent',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
    url:  'backend/admin_speler.php',    // override for form's 'action' attribute 
    type:  'post'       // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
}; 
// bind to the form's submit event 
$('#frm_zoek_speler').submit(function() { 
    // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first 
    // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false; 
});
```

using: jQuery v2.1.3

Comment: Do you want to bind a submit action to any forms like $('form').submit(function() { // ... } or get data from all forms on the page and bind it into one big submit?

Comment: i want to bind ALL forms to a submit function, so no collecting all data from all forms. I just dont want to create submit fnctions for each form, which can be a lot if the found playerslist is big. So i hope it is possible to do this at once with just 1 submit function. i hope i made myself clear enough:)

Comment: added jQuery version to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a single event to a element parent to all desired forms:

```
$("#parent").on('submit', 'form', function(){
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false;
});
```

In case you're using a jQuery version previous than 1.7, you can use:

```
$("#parent").delegate('form', 'submit', function(){
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: #parents should be a div and all forms should be placed inside this div?

Comment: `$(#parent)` can be any element selector. Even `$(document)`. But usually you'll have a better adequate selector.

Comment: * any element selector ancestor to the forms

Comment: I used <div id="allforms">here my forms</div> Thanks again for the solution AND!! explanation.